# corpus to text with nltk?

Tags: python, nltk, spacy

Hello I download a corpus using NLTK

```
phrase = nltk.corpus.conll2002.iob_sents('esp.testb')[0]
```

That return:

> [('La', 'DA', 'B-LOC'),  ('Coruña', 'NC', 'I-LOC'),  (',', 'Fc', 'O'),
> ('23', 'Z', 'O'),  ('may', 'NC', 'O'),  ('(', 'Fpa', 'O'),  ('EFECOM',
> 'NP', 'B-ORG'),

The questions is about how can get the complete sentence I am using the following code:

```
' '.join([w[0] for w in phrase])
phrase = ' '.join([w[0] for w in phrase])
```

But I get this

> 'La Coruña , 23 may ( EFECOM ) .'

Instead of

> 'La Coruña, 23 may (EFECOM).'

how can I get the second sentence?

Thanks

Comment: it may need to create more complex code than `" ".join()` and decide for every element separatelly if it has to add space or not. Or you may remove spaces after adding you will `phrase = phrase.replace("( ", "(").replace(" )", ")").replace(" .", ".")`. But it also need to add more `replace` to remove from all possible places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoNLL corpora usually don't contain information on spaces, so it's impossible to perfectly reconstruct the original sentence.

You can use a heuristic to not put spaces before commas or closing parens or some other characters, but it's usually just easier to separate everything with spaces.